# Cambiar color del borde por defecto de un checkbox en Ionic 5

Tags: ionic

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Ionic 5 y he tratado de seguir la [documentación del checkbox](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/checkbox) para cambiar el color del borde que viene por defecto.

```
<ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-checkbox mode="md"></ion-checkbox>
    <ion-label>Acepto los <a (click)="openTerms()">Términos y Condiciones</a></ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

global.scss

```
/*
 * App Global CSS
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Put style rules here that you want to apply globally. These styles are for
 * the entire app and not just one component.
 */

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/core.css";

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/structure.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/typography.css";
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/display.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/padding.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css";
@import "~@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css";

/* Checkbox */
.ion-checkbox {
  --border-color: red;
  --border-color-checked :red;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El color del borde no cambia. Qué estoy pasando por alto?

Mi objetivo es poder cambiar el color del borde que viene por defecto en el checkbox a uno personalizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quita el punto, no es el nombre de una clase, es una etiqueta.

```
ion-checkbox {
  --border-color: red;
  --border-color-checked :red;
}
```